# Nested Collections with MsgPack

Tags: c#, dictionary, msgpack

I have following generic dictionary inside class I want to pack/unpack with MsgPack:

`public Dictionary<string, Object> values { get; set; }`

Packing and unpacking works staight out of the box in common cases, but if a new dictionary 
`new Dictionary<string, Object>` to values dictionary, like this:

`values.add("nested", nestedValues);`

After unpacking nestedValues has a type of `MsgPackObjectDictionary` which I'm unable to convert back to .NET Dictionary. So how to handle nested Collections with MsgPack?

EDIT:

More defined data classes seems to be one way to work around this problem:
[Deserialize a type containing a Dictionary property using ServiceStack JsonSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14716979/deserialize-a-type-containing-a-dictionary-property-using-servicestack-jsonseria)

Answer (score 0):

Many serializers have issues handling `object` Types since the serialization formats doesn't have a concept of "runtime type" so the deserializer doesn't have any idea of what it should be serialized back into. This is primarily a problem with static languages which needs to know the exact type to deserialize into whereas dynamic languages are able to leave it as a primitive value.

The Serializers that do support `object` Types have to embed custom serializer-specific extensions to embed this extra information which now couples the payload to a specific serializer implementation which is why unknown types like `object` and Interfaces should be avoided when serializing DTO's (Data Transfer Objects).